# update database by decrement stock C# and mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have two drop down lists that effect each over, for example if you choose UK in the first drop down the second drop down will be populated from the UK table, if you select Germany it will be populated via German table and so on. each table contains the same three columns Specie, Specie_Price and Stock. I would like to reduce the stock integer by 1 each time a specie is chose from the second list and a button click happens. I am lost on how to build a update statement to do this on the selection from the second drop down, I would appriciate any help at all. I will post code bellow to give you better understanding on what I mean.

**code for first drop down list on page load (country selection)**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        MySqlCommand cd2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Country", cs); 
        cs.Open();
        MySqlDataReader ddlCountry = cd2.ExecuteReader();
        ddlcountry.DataSource = ddlCountry;
        ddlcountry.DataValueField = "Country";
        ddlcountry.DataTextField = "Country";
        ddlcountry.DataBind();
        cs.Close();
        cs.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**Code that populates the drop down with the Specie from the country chosen**

```
protected void ddlcountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlcountry.Text != string.Empty)
    {
        MySqlCommand cd = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}_Animals",
                                           ddlcountry.Text), cs);
        cs.Open();
        MySqlDataReader ddlSpecie = cd.ExecuteReader();
        DdPetPist.DataSource = ddlSpecie;
        DdPetPist.DataValueField = "Specie";
        DdPetPist.DataTextField = "Specie";
        DdPetPist.DataBind();
        cs.Close();
        cs.Dispose();
    }
}
```

so the what I want is that when they have chose there country then the specie they click button and id decrements the Stock of the table chosen buy 1.
I hope some one can help, thank you.

**!!UPDATE ANSWER!!**

Got it working 100% in the end,

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string selection_price = DdPetPist.SelectedValue;
        var myquery = string.Format("UPDATE Animals SET Stock = Stock - 1 WHERE Specie ='{1}' and Country ='{0}'", ddlcountry.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim(), selection_price);
        using (MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection(connection string here))
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(myquery, c))
        {
            c.Open(); 
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            c.Close();


        }

    }
```

Comment: The design of having a table of animals per country smells very bad. Are you sure you are not better with just a "country" attribute in your animals table?

Comment: hmm, i though that first of all, but I found this way to work well. only problem now is trying to get it to decrease the stock once the animal in the country is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, hook up a button click event handler, and then in the handler do something like this:

```
var sql = string.Format(
    "UPDATE {0}_Animals SET Stock = Stock - 1 WHERE Specie = @Specie",
        ddlcountry.Text);
using (MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection(cString))
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, c))
{
    c.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Specie", specie);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

where `cString` is the connection string and `specie` is the identifier. I'm not 100% sure where that comes from, but I think the drop down lists selected value.

Comment: thank you, problem is it looks like I can use it due to specie begin a column.

Comment: @Beep: what? I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: it dose not work, but im going to try and alter my program to only use one table with Specie, Price, Stock and Country then i may how to use your answer.

Comment: @Beep, I'm a bit confused. You stated that `each table contains the same three columns Specie, Specie_Price and Stock`, thus the `sql` I'm building should pick the right country table. Did I read the question wrong, or is your database not quite how it was stated in the question? Either way, the approach is the exact same, once you get the statement right you'll get what you want.

Comment: @Micheal Perrenoud OK thank you i shall try to get your answer to work, at the moment `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Specie", Specie);` Specie is throwing up a error stating that it does not exist in current context

Comment: @Beep: as I stated in the answer. I don't know where `specie` comes from here. You'll need to declare that variable yourself. All I know is it's the identifier for that record. I think it comes from the `SelectedValue` of one of the drop-downs, but you know better than I there.